# How to debug npm install execution

Tags: node.js, npm

What´s the recommended way of debugging an npm install operation?

I have an exception being throw (similar to https://github.com/hyperform/hyperform/issues/63 or https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858) and would like to know how to debug the source code of it.

Answer (score 35):

From [NPM's wiki:](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)
"If you are having trouble with `npm install`, use the `--verbose` option to have more details."

(Not to be confused with `npm_debug=1` flag, which is only valid for debugging the process of installing NPM itself).

Comment: Documentation has moved to: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install